# How to reset the performance recommendation on Azure SQL database managed instance?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have a database as Azure SQL managed instance and we've had some recommendations to create indexes. Since then we have worked on the solution and we have changed our data structure to make it more efficient, or we have added the suggested indexes but with a different name.

From the [Microsoft articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-advisor-find-recommendations-portal#manually-apply-recommendations-through-t-sql), I expect not to see the recommendation after a couple of days, but I still can see recommendation that has "last update" in April (+7 months ago).

> manually applied recommendations will remain active and shown in the
> list of recommendations for 24-48 hrs.

Why do I still see them and how do I clear this view without discarding them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can only discard the recommendations that you want to remove from the list.

Canceling recommendations are done when in Pending, Validating, or Success status.

You can raise a support ticket for the support engineer to investigate your scenario.